# Changing name of column generated by EF

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

I have two models:

```
[Table("aspnet_Users")]
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public Guid UserID { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserLog> UserLogs { get; set; }
}

[Table("UsersLog")]
public class UserLog
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

And I want to get UserID from column named UserID. I've tried this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UserAll>().HasMany(u => u.UserLogs).WithOptional().Map(m => m.MapKey("UserID"));
```

from question: [How to specify a column Name for EF5 navigation property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16874887/how-to-specify-a-column-name-for-ef5-navigation-property), but it generate:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
[Extent1].[DateTime] AS [DateTime], 
[Extent1].[UserID] AS [UserID], 
[Extent1].[User_UserID] AS [User_UserID]
FROM [dbo].[UsersLog] AS [Extent1]
```

And throwing an exception because i don't have User_UserID column in my database. How to repair this?

Comment: why u use alias for Extent1?

Comment: I don't know. What is alias?

Comment: Try putting `User_UserID` instead of `UserID` in your `modelBuilder` query.

Comment: `SELECT 
    [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
    [Extent1].[DateTime] AS [DateTime], 
    [Extent1].[User_UserID] AS [User_UserID], 
    [Extent1].[User_UserID] AS [User_UserID1]
    FROM [dbo].[UsersLog] AS [Extent1]`

Comment: as you have a navigation key as mentioned in the accepted answer of the question, who's link you posted, therefore you have to use `WithOptional(i => i.User)` or `WithRequired(i => i.User)` instead of the parameterless version of `WithOptional()` that you are using

Comment: Ok, stupid question, thanks a lot.